# Is there a way to make my numpad be just a numpad?

Tags: workflow

I use my numpad to type in exact parameters.  Quite often I've not quite gotten my field selected and when I hit a number my view changes to some weird angle or restriction I can't get out of and it's a pain to go figure out how to get back to exactly the thing I was looking at seconds before.  How do I make the numpad just for numbers?

Comment: I can't reproduce the behaviour you describe. If you click in one of the input fields, then use the numpad to input numbers, it should do exactly that. However, if you move your mouse back into the viewport and click on an object, the numpad gets bind to the viewport.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Blender Preferences > Keymap.

Set search type to Key-Binding and search for numpad.

[image]

Scroll down to 3D View, and press X for the keybinds for the numpad

[image]

Comment: Wonderful!  THANK YOU!